# Slow screen capture code on OSX. Why?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I have implemented some screen capture code which can be [viewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32466/reviewing-c-function-which-captures-the-screen)

I'm using GetTimeInNanoseconds from [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html)

The function is called every 100ms. I've timed how many milliseconds it takes to execute part of the function, namely:

```
screenShotStart = GetTimeInNanoseconds();
CGImageRef image = CGWindowListCreateImage(rect, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow|kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow, 0, kCGWindowImageDefault);
CGImageRelease(image);

screenShotStop = GetTimeInNanoseconds();
screenShotElapsed = screenShotStop - screenShotStart;
/* Current Delta Time */
screenShotElapsedF = ((float) screenShotElapsed)/1000000.0f;
/* Smooth Delta Time */
screenShotTime = 0.9f*screenShotTime + 0.1f*screenShotElapsedF;
```

The time measurements below show the results. I'm amazed at how slow it is and I'm wondering why. Is there an experienced Cocoa/Core Graphics OSX developer out there who can explain it to me? And possibly tell me how it should be fixed?

Smooth : Averaged delta time in milliseconds.
Current: Latest, most current delta time in milliseconds.

```
    Screenshot profile : 0.242122ms (smooth) | 2.421224ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 0.970972ms (smooth) | 7.530621ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 1.421471ms (smooth) | 5.475956ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 2.172416ms (smooth) | 8.930922ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 2.840984ms (smooth) | 8.858095ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 3.633541ms (smooth) | 10.766552ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 4.383532ms (smooth) | 11.133454ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 4.876161ms (smooth) | 9.309816ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 5.043479ms (smooth) | 6.549345ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 5.465037ms (smooth) | 9.259055ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 5.709429ms (smooth) | 7.908960ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 5.971393ms (smooth) | 8.329066ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.127830ms (smooth) | 7.535762ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.533566ms (smooth) | 10.185198ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.661420ms (smooth) | 7.812104ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.648901ms (smooth) | 6.536235ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.564128ms (smooth) | 5.801169ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 6.946393ms (smooth) | 10.386786ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 7.231448ms (smooth) | 9.796943ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 7.408576ms (smooth) | 9.002735ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 7.901027ms (smooth) | 12.333084ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 7.832513ms (smooth) | 7.215887ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.077989ms (smooth) | 10.287273ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.032367ms (smooth) | 7.621767ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.203003ms (smooth) | 9.738728ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.525432ms (smooth) | 11.427292ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.672282ms (smooth) | 9.993936ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.818027ms (smooth) | 10.129727ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 8.968993ms (smooth) | 10.327700ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 9.755873ms (smooth) | 16.837791ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.098254ms (smooth) | 13.179691ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.007771ms (smooth) | 9.193431ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 9.730317ms (smooth) | 7.233225ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 9.923961ms (smooth) | 11.666759ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.171064ms (smooth) | 12.395005ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.436771ms (smooth) | 12.828136ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.752213ms (smooth) | 13.591184ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.677605ms (smooth) | 10.006127ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.696332ms (smooth) | 10.864876ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.836714ms (smooth) | 12.100148ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.384002ms (smooth) | 6.309598ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.512785ms (smooth) | 11.671834ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 10.594671ms (smooth) | 11.331652ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 11.022106ms (smooth) | 14.869019ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 11.056261ms (smooth) | 11.363660ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 13.173499ms (smooth) | 32.228638ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 12.901811ms (smooth) | 10.456617ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 12.511471ms (smooth) | 8.998418ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 60.684856ms (smooth) | 494.245331ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 111.287766ms (smooth) | 566.713928ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 118.577721ms (smooth) | 184.187302ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 126.834038ms (smooth) | 201.140869ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 233.015961ms (smooth) | 1188.653198ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 293.934875ms (smooth) | 842.205017ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 282.354095ms (smooth) | 178.127045ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 297.604187ms (smooth) | 434.854919ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 300.026642ms (smooth) | 321.828796ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 298.798157ms (smooth) | 287.741913ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 307.527008ms (smooth) | 386.086761ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 294.194061ms (smooth) | 174.197708ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 286.482117ms (smooth) | 217.074570ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 277.750549ms (smooth) | 199.166428ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 271.708069ms (smooth) | 217.325623ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 245.042664ms (smooth) | 5.053972ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 221.163406ms (smooth) | 6.250124ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 208.384155ms (smooth) | 93.371033ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 207.589813ms (smooth) | 200.440811ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 223.785492ms (smooth) | 369.546631ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 221.480774ms (smooth) | 200.738419ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 230.090012ms (smooth) | 307.573181ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 254.507935ms (smooth) | 474.269287ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 283.468353ms (smooth) | 544.112122ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 285.878754ms (smooth) | 307.572601ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 300.691986ms (smooth) | 434.011261ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 301.684082ms (smooth) | 310.613220ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 272.227661ms (smooth) | 7.119990ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 246.098129ms (smooth) | 10.932533ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 281.438873ms (smooth) | 599.505737ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 291.068756ms (smooth) | 377.737671ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 262.161163ms (smooth) | 1.992869ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 236.614410ms (smooth) | 6.693653ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 243.460983ms (smooth) | 305.080231ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 240.609909ms (smooth) | 214.950256ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 266.002258ms (smooth) | 494.533417ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 276.689453ms (smooth) | 372.874268ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 278.445312ms (smooth) | 294.248047ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 268.703094ms (smooth) | 181.023148ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 242.027161ms (smooth) | 1.943824ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 218.654465ms (smooth) | 8.300381ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 211.597733ms (smooth) | 148.087173ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 191.547241ms (smooth) | 11.092879ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 181.838150ms (smooth) | 94.456367ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 164.788208ms (smooth) | 11.338873ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 151.486023ms (smooth) | 31.766415ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 159.313858ms (smooth) | 229.764404ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 220.536041ms (smooth) | 771.535706ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 198.653290ms (smooth) | 1.708489ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 180.131805ms (smooth) | 13.438550ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 307.717621ms (smooth) | 1455.989990ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 477.049713ms (smooth) | 2001.038452ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 434.271057ms (smooth) | 49.263458ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 392.732391ms (smooth) | 18.884504ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 396.588654ms (smooth) | 431.295227ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 410.529907ms (smooth) | 536.001404ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 420.648346ms (smooth) | 511.714478ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 421.814819ms (smooth) | 432.313385ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 398.381866ms (smooth) | 187.485214ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 359.150482ms (smooth) | 6.068115ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 395.477631ms (smooth) | 722.422058ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 356.116364ms (smooth) | 1.864945ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 321.195648ms (smooth) | 6.909203ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 313.617981ms (smooth) | 245.419037ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 291.778534ms (smooth) | 95.223839ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 275.232025ms (smooth) | 126.313583ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 299.395660ms (smooth) | 516.868530ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 289.037140ms (smooth) | 195.810669ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 472.922241ms (smooth) | 2127.887939ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 425.895874ms (smooth) | 2.658584ms (current) 
    Screenshot profile : 404.271606ms (smooth) | 209.653427ms (current)
```

EDIT: Download [profile results](http://wikisend.com/download/665000/trace.zip)

Comment: Did you follow this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Listings/ScreenSnapshot_ScreenSnapshotAppDelegate_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011158-ScreenSnapshot_ScreenSnapshotAppDelegate_h-DontLinkElementID_8??

Comment: Yes. but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Have you profiled your app in Instruments?

Comment: No. But for the lack of better and more precise terminology, I think the frequent calls to do screen captures are building up on a queue somewhere because the OS is putting a lock on the desktop while it's capturing. When the OS is done capturing, it unlocks and then there's a bunch of capture events on the queue which causes the whole thing to become laggy and eventually freeze up. So my question really is: Is there a way to force the OS _not_ to put a lock on the desktop while it's capturing?

Comment: If you haven't profiled yet, your next step is to profile, not try to force different OS behaviors (and their consequences) based on guesses and theories. Run your app under Instruments and see what is *actually* taking the time. Even if all you find is proof that your guess was right, that's still reason enough to do it.

Comment: Peter, the problem is that I can't profile it because everything locks up within seconds. All I'm doing is calling CGWindowListCreateImage over and over again in a while loop. I don't understand why that's happening. Is there a minimum amount of millisecond that I have to sleep before I call again? Even at 100ms sleeps everything locks up even though it takes a little longer to do so.

Comment: Peter. I edited my original post and posted a link to a zip file which contains the profile results. Can you (or somebody else) take a look at the profile results and tell me what's going on? I'm not sure how to interpret the results. The zip file also contains the source code that I'm running.

Comment: Not sure if its an issue for you but the way you convert RGBA to RGB is not the most efficient approach. Either use vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB888 which uses SIMD registers (and simple to use) or  better yet OpenGL to do the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The CGWindow API is not intended for high-frame-rate capturing. For one thing, it's not capturing the currently-displayed screen image. It is generalized to potentially capture various portions of the content. It can include or exclude windows, desktop elements, shadows, etc. That means it's composing a new image for every call. And, yes, that means that it has to lock the backing buffer of all of the windows.

Apple provides a pair of technical Q&A articles about capturing the screen contents. One is for capturing single images, where they recommend the use of [`CGDisplayCreateImage()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayCreateImage). The other is for capturing a movie of screen activity over time, where they recommend the use of AV Foundation.
[Technical Q&A QA1741: How to take an image snapshot of the screen on Mac OS X Lion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1741/_index.html)
[Technical Q&A QA1740: How to capture screen activity to a movie file using AV Foundation on Mac OS X Lion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/_index.html)

Comment: Guess which API that TeamViewer still uses today? That's right! CGWindow API! Which explains why the entire machine chugs whenever it's capturing desktop images! Maybe I can convince them to update things now that 10.7 has been out for a few years.